# Submit button Navigation step in custom Form Element

Tags: sitecore-forms

I have a multipage Sitecore Form and created a custom Form Element for the same and added it. It has 2 submit buttons:

[image]

1. the 'Register User' button will redirect to some URL(handled by javascript in the cshtml)
2. for the 'Continue as guest', I want to add functionality to this button's on-click so that it goes to the next page of the Sitecore Form.

How do I accomplish point 2?

I know the OOTB feature is there to add the navigation step 'Next'. But these buttons are coming from the Custom form element (cshtml)so how do I apply the same 'Next' functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can refer [this](https://smartsitecore.com/en/call-custom-javascript-on-sitecore-forms-submit/) and utilize the custom scripts method described. You can easily use the method described in the lines "call js function from external file" which in your case would the cshtml file of yours.